# Declaration expected in VB dll

Tags: vb.net, dll

First of all thanking everyone....

I am currently working on VB. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

The piece of code below is a console application which builds without any error.

```
    Imports System.Net


Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim address As IPAddress
        Dim remoteIP As System.Net.IPEndPoint
        Dim socketAddress As System.Net.SocketAddress

        Try
            address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.187")
            remoteIP = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(address, 0)

            socketAddress = remoteIP.Serialize()

            Console.WriteLine("Address Family :" & remoteIP.AddressFamily.ToString())
            Console.WriteLine("IP :" & remoteIP.Address.ToString() & "Port :" & remoteIP.Port.ToString())
            Console.WriteLine("Socket address :" & socketAddress.ToString())


        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString())


        End Try

    End Sub


End Module
```

In the next program which is a dll the same gives error saying "Declaration Expected for addr, remoteIP and socketAddr"

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Class1


End Class
Public Class ethernet

    Dim addr As IPAddress
    Dim remoteIP As System.Net.IPEndPoint
    Dim socketAddr As System.Net.SocketAddress

    addr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.187")
    remoteIP = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(addr,0)

    socketAddr = remoteIP.Serialize()



End Class
```

Can anybody tell me why is this happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the second class `ethernet` is not contained within a Method, therefore you are only declaring the `addr, remoteIP` and `socketAddr` variables.

To make that work just put the code in a method, like:

```
Public Class ethernet
    Public Function SerializeSocket(address As String) As System.Net.SocketAddress
        Dim addr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.187")
        Dim remoteIP As System.Net.IPEndPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(addr,0)
        Return remoteIP.Serialize()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hey no worries, I actually missed the comment. Yes you can put this code in a Sub and do further processing afterwards, rather than returning the serialized endpoint. The class itself could contain some Properties which are initialized when the class is created (using Sub New()).